# Magento widgets: How do I create a new condition for "show attribute?"

Tags: php, magento, widget, content-management-system

Hopefully I can explain this correctly:

In Magento when I go to CMS Widgets > Widget Options, I see "Select condition of product for filtering" - this only contains a few values:  Best Seller, Featured Products, etc...

I want to create a widget that I can add to a front page tabbed section that when you click on a specific manufacturer's logo (or name), a few products will show up in the area of the selected tab. Pretty standard CSS/jQuery tab.

I cannot find a way to add a filter widget within Magento that allows me to do this.

I can do it for featured products and other things, but is there a way to filter by an attribute?